# Insert and check data in PostgreSql database

Tags: java, database, postgresql

I have the following problem. Using Java application i need to insert data from external XML file to database table every 1 second.

In addition, I have to perform a select/update query on the same table.

Table is cleaned every few days. My question is: how to solve it optimally? Everything must work `live`. We can't allow a situation where there is a time shift( records are not checked every 1s).

Any ideas?

Comment: I figure you have a certain amount of data that you receive via a certain channel, on a regular basis, (let's say in every second,) and you want to insert these data into PostgreSQL db immediately. So let's put it this way: you have to insert a batch of records in very second. It would be important to know the amount of the data in a batch. How many records do you need to insert in a batch? It would be also good to know the channel via which you receive the data.

Comment: About 10-20 records. File is generated via external server. I receive data by URL `http://example.com/get_xml.php?param=2

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how complex you plan your application to be, you might consider JPA/Hibernate to access your database. It makes a lot simpler to access your DB (because you manipulate POJO's to access your data) but the downside is that it is not optimal in term of performance (manipulating raw sql and raw data will always be faster than manipulating objects).

For your job check, I would set up quartz which will offer you the possibility to schedule jobs periodically.

Your question is kind of vague to give more hints. Is it a web application? a Java EE one? A heavy-client? How bad do you need high-performance? Do you want to create a small-application with no future written on a pizza-napkin or do you plan to have an application that will extend in the future.

Comment: The application is quiet complex. I'm grabbing data from XML (10 new records per second)
Data from this file are insert into table in database, every 1 second. This is already done. 

Bigger problem is checking this data live. We have a PHP application, where user insert data to another table(for example `userdata`=`1234`)

I need to run application(JAVA) in the background, which checks every 1s if userdata exists in table. 
The most important part is no to skip any data while checking. Performance is important. Expansion is likely to be required in the future.

Comment: Then I would use raw SQL (PreparedStatement etc...) to access your data. Setting up Quartz seems also like a good option as it will bring you a whole set of handy features to perform job scheduling. What do you mean by skip data?

Comment: I mean, that adds the records in the second, the next must be checked at the latest. We can not allow a situation in which the data will be checked later (for example, 3 seconds after they are added to the database)

Comment: Unless you are in a real-time environment, you can not have an absolute guarantee of that. You can have a best-effort strategy but you can never be sure that there won't be other processes interfering with your Java code. There is also a bunch of latency created by I/O's.

Answer (score 0):

10-20 records per second is not a large amount. Anyway, if you have any performance problem, make sure you use [JDBC batch inserts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29):

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO table_name (field_name1, field_name2) VALUES (?, ?)");

stmt.setInt(1, 2000);
stmt.setString(2, "String value");
stmt.addBatch();

stmt.setInt(1, 3000);
stmt.setString(2, "Other String");
stmt.addBatch();

// submit the batch for execution
int[] insertCounts = stmt.executeBatch();
```

Comment: Adding data is not a problem. Bigger problem is checking the data after insert. I have only one second after insert to check if records exists in table. I do not know if there will be a problem when checking data. After one day in the base will be about 2 million records. I also have to make an inquiry select a few times and have only one second to do that